# How to find if an element in an array that matches a certain condition exists?

Tags: javascript

Typescript newb question, but I need the fastest way to find if an element with certain condition exists. Is there something like `arr.exists(e=>{e.....bla bla bla})` in typescript (where ar is my array of objects).

Comment: It has nothing to do with Typescript.

Comment: That's way too broad, please provide a [mcve] or at least your original data and the expected result.

Comment: You need [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: Thanks Satpal. That is the correct question.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz what does it have to do with, if not with typescript, kindly respond?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic, your problem is in no way related to Angular. You don't mention Angular anywhere in your post, nor use any Angular-specific syntax. Why did you put this tag back in?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking is `.find()` method of array. It's not anyhow different in TypeScript. [Link to docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Please remove your question, so that I can try and delete my question. I think it will attract vultures for its deletion.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic For future reference, *what you asked is a question*, Borys provided an answer, *an answer is a response to a question*